# Android does not open aac stream

Tags: android, stream, playback, aac

For over two weeks I have been trying to open an arc stream. It is an online radio I am building an app for. I have successfully opened the stream on iOS from the first try but I am unable to open it from Android.

Here is what I tried:

Used Media Player as described in Media Payback page on developer.android.com. It is found here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html . It came with a whole load of issues, trying to solve one error just got me into others.

Tried OpenMXPlayer, which is an open source android player the should be able to play aac streams. Actually it is, but not this stream. You can find OpenMXPlayer on google code at this link: https://code.google.com/p/android-openmxplayer/ . Any attempt to play my stream resulted in failed to initiate extractor error.

Tried aacplayer-android and aacdecoder-android. It works fine on many streams, however on this one it simply doesn't. Every attempt of playing the stream ends in java.lang.NullPointerException.

The stream I am trying to open can be found at this address: http://live.mixcraiova.ro:8241

I am looking for a piece of code that can open and play this stream as I am unable to figure out for myself how to do it or where the errors come from. I am sorry for asking for code to open a specific stream, but I cannot find any problem with what I did. All other 3 attempts successfully open other aac streams, but not this one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe its phone issue. Some phones have buggy firmware